# Como trabalhar com Views do banco de dados no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

*Views* não tem uma chave primária então me gera o erro:

> Erro: The number of primary key values passed must match number of
>   primary key values defined on the entity.

Como poderia fazer para evitar este erro?

```
public ActionResult AtualizaCliente(int id)
{
    sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();
    return View(dao.vcliente.Find(id));
}
```

Comment: Você tem essa PK definida em seu model ? Porque o que o erro ta dizendo é que você não tem a PK definida...

Comment: Você está usando o EntityFramework não é? Qual versão?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, sim, você tem razão sobre a mensagem do erro, mais na minha dúvida em falo que estou trabalhando com uma Views,então eu não tenho uma chave primária.

Comment: Se não tem chave primária, o `Find` não vai funcionar. Você pode tentar obter de outra forma: `return View(dao.vcliente.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == id));`

Comment: @itasouza Será que a questão não seria **Como mapear views do banco de dados no EntityFramework?**

Comment: No ASP.NET MVC o termo *View* é outra coisa totalmente diferente de uma *View* no banco de dados.

Answer (score 4):

Está **totalmente errado** trabalhar em ASP.NET MVC e Entity Framework sem usar chaves primárias. Usar Entity Framework pressupõe o uso de chaves primárias em todas as entidades. É uma característica de design do Framework que simplesmente não pode ser burlada.

[Na questão abaixo do SO as respostas são consensuais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key). Portanto, defina uma chave primária para poder usar o `Find`.

Tomemos como exemplo a suposta classe usada pela pergunta, chamada `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente 
{
    [Key]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Considere as reticências acima como os demais campos que fazem parte do seu *Model*.

Do jeito em que está, já está correto. Seu *Model* já possui uma chave primária (anotei como `[Key]`) e o `Find` já funciona.

Comment: Você sabe como é possível definir uma chave primária em uma Views? O Entity Framework não atende isso?

Comment: Você está entendendo errado o conceito. No MVC, não se define chaves primárias em Views. Views fazem parte da apresentação do sistema, ou seja, o lugar em que se define como a informação deve aparecer para o usuário. O lugar em que se define chaves é o **Model**, que é onde se define as entidades e as relações entre elas.

Comment: Não leve a mal, mais a sua explicação conceitual é muito complicada, tanto nesta como em outras perguntas que pude verificar, pois existe várias formas de se criar o models é no meu caso foi criada pelo Entity Framework ,  dentro do Model.tt é criado a classe de cada tabela é lá não tem uma definição de chave primária. Não seria mais simples no lugar de uma resposta conceitual um exemplo no código?

Comment: @itasouza O Model.tt é um antigo método de criar uma classe através de uma modelagem feita através de um arquivo EDMX. Isto nada tem a ver com a não necessidade de criação de chave primária. Esta interpretação é totalmente sua. Vou colocar um exemplo pra que isso fique mais claro.